# Cannot remove inputs array with filter

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to remove an input field with filter function but it's not working.

In the following code add operation works fine but remove operation is not working properly ,it is not removing the corresponding element.Another problem the values on the inputs fields not present when the component re-renders.so experts guide me how i can achieve removing the corresponding row when the remove button is clicked and the input values should not be reset when the component re-renders

So when I refresh the page and click to remove an input it will clear all other input data. How can I fix this problem ?

Update adding full component in question:

```
const Agreement = (props) => {
  const { agreement, editable, teamData, teamId, fetchTeamData } = props;
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [showErrors, setShowErrors] = useState(false);
  const [errorsArr, setErrorsArr] = useState();

  const initialFormState = {
    rule_0: teamData.rules.rule_0,
    rule_1: teamData.rules.rule_1,
    rule_2: teamData.rules.rule_2,
    rule_3: teamData.rules.rule_3,
    creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,
  };

  const [updateTeamData, setUpdateTeamData] = useState(initialFormState);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(
    teamData.rules.map((el) => ({
      ...el,
      guid: uuidV4(),
    }))
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // Add more input
  const addInputs = () => {
    setInputs([...inputs, { name: `rule_${inputs.length + 1}` }]);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const removeInputs = (index) => {
    const newList = inputs.filter((item, i) => index !== i); // <-- compare for matching index
    setInputs(newList);
  };

  const clearInput = (dataName) => {
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => {
      delete prevState[dataName];
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEditing(false);
    // Send update request

    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/teams/team/${teamId}`, updateTeamData);

    // If no validation errors were found
    // Validation errors don't throw errors, it returns an array to display.
    if (res.data.validationErrors === undefined) {
      // Clear any errors
      setErrorsArr([]);
      // Hide the errors component
      setShowErrors(false);
      // Call update profiles on parent
      fetchTeamData();
    } else {
      // Set errors
      setErrorsArr(res.data.validationErrors.errors);
      // Show the errors component
      setShowErrors(true);
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (agreement === "default") {
      setTitle(defaultTitle);
      // setInputs(teamData.rules);
    } else {
      setTitle(agreement.title ?? "");
    }
  }, [agreement, teamData]);

  // console.log("teamData.rules", teamData);
  console.log("inputs", inputs);

  return (
    <div className="team-agreement-container">
      {!editing && (
        <>
          <h4 className="team-agreement-rules-title">{title}</h4>
          {editable && (
            <div className="team-agreement-rules">
              <EditOutlined
                className="team-agreement-rules-edit-icon"
                onClick={() => setEditing(true)}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          {teamData.rules.map((rule, index) => (
            <div className="team-agreement-rule-item" key={`rule-${index}`}>
              {rule ? (
                <div>
                  <h4 className="team-agreement-rule-item-title">
                    {`Rule #${index + 1}`}
                  </h4>
                  <p className="team-agreement-rule-item-description">
                    - {rule}
                  </p>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
      {/* Edit rules form */}
      {editing && (
        <div className="team-agreement-form">
          {showErrors && <ModalErrorHandler errorsArr={errorsArr} />}
          <h1>Rules</h1>
          {inputs.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
              <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={data.guid}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="agreement-remove-button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    removeInputs(idx);
                    clearInput(`rule_${idx}`);
                  }}
                >
                  <Remove />
                </button>
                <input
                  name={`rule_${idx}`}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={teamData.rules[idx]}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          {inputs.length < 4 && (
            <div className="team-agreement-add-rule">
              <button type="submit" onClick={addInputs}>
                <Add />
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="div-button">
            <button className="save-button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Save
            </button>
            <button className="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Agreement;
```

When i do `console.log(inputs)` this is the data that I got:

> 0: 0: "t" 1: "e" 2: "s" guid: "e18595a5-e30b-4b71-8fc2-0ad9c0e140b2"
> **proto**: Object 1: 0: "d" 1: "a" 2: "s" 3: "d" 4: "a" 5: "s" guid: "537ca359-511b-4bc6-9583-553ea6ebf544" ...

Comment: did you console.log the index in the removeInputs functions

Comment: No I didn't @AbuDujanaMahalail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are using the array index as the React key. When you mutate the underlying data and reorder or add/remove elements in the middle of the array then the elements shift around but the React key previously used doesn't move with the elements.

When you remove an element then all posterior elements shift forward and the index, as key, remains the same so React bails on rerendering the elements. The array will be one element shorter in length and so you'll see the last item removed instead of the one you *actually* removed.

## Solution

Use a React key that is intrinsic to the elements being mapped, unique properties like guids, `ids`, `name`, etc... any property of the element that guarantees sufficient uniqueness among the dataset (i.e. the siblings).

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules);

const removeInputs = (index) => {
  // compare for matching index
  setInputs(inputs => inputs.filter((item, i) => index !== i));
};

{inputs.map((data, idx) => {
  return (
    <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={data.id}> // <-- use a unique property
      <button
        type="button"
        className="agreement-remove-button"
        onClick={() => {
          removeInputs(idx);
          clearInput(`rule_${idx}`);
        }}
      >
        <Remove />
      </button>
      <input
        name={`rule_${idx}`}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={teamData.rules[idx]}
      />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

If your `teamData.rules` initial state value doesn't have any unique properties to use then you can map this to a new array and add a sufficient `id` property.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  guid: generateId()***,
})));
```

**** this is a function you need to define yourself, or import from a module like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)****

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  guid: uuidV4(),
})));

// Add more input
const addInputs = () => {
  setInputs(inputs => [
    ...inputs,
    {
      name: `rule_${inputs.length + 1}`,
      guid: uuidV4();
    },
  ]);
};
```

Then when mapping use the `guid` property.

```
<div className="agreement-form-grid" key={data.guid}>
```

Comment: I am getting this error `ReferenceError: generateId is not defined`

Comment: @nathan Sorry, I thought it was more clear, but you will need to define this function or import a module that helps generate GUIDs. I added a note to this effect in my answer. Again, apologies for any confusion.

Comment: after I added the `uuidV4` module and edit some codes in my project, it work with the removeClick function but when it remove it removed the last input field not the one I clicked on. I will update full component in my question

Comment: @nathan I've pored over your updated question and nothing is jumping out to me. Is it possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox example that reproduces your issue and link it in your question? I suspect using the index as part of the name (`name={\`rule_${idx}\`}`) in the input may also be causing you trouble since the name value will change when the indices shift.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-chebyshev-w8o2u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @nathan You weren't kidding about the "wait 1s"... I applied my suggestions against your code and it seems to work for me, I can remove arbitrary inputs. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-remove-inputs-array-with-filter-io651

Comment: @nathan change your key to key={data.guid} based on the above answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are trying to compare index with array item in `filter` method. You should use the second argument in `filter` which denotes the array index of the current iterating item

```
const removeInputs = (index) => {
    const newList = inputs.filter((item,i) => index !== i);
    setInputs(newList);
  };
```

Comment: after i changed to your code it just remove the last item in array not the one I click on

Answer (score 1):

That's your solution, you are trying with `item` but you are comparing it with `index` that's wrong. You should do it like this,

```
const newList = inputs.filter((item, key) => index !== key);
```

Comment: after i changed to your code it just remove the last item in array not the one I click on